# catkin_add_env_hooks cross-platform?

Tags: ros, catkin, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are implications of [catkin_add_env_hooks](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-add-env-hooks) and Windows? Do they just get ignored, with the intent that they're mainly there to provide window-dressing stuff like tab completion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137091/catkin_add_env_hooks-cross-platform?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Environment hooks are not only available on Linux. And they don't only provide stuff like tab completion.

It is perfectly valid and encouraged to not only have `sh`/`bash` environment hooks but also `bat` equivalents. E.g. the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH must be available on all platforms and is also defined in an environment hook:

- https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/indigo-devel/core/roslib/env-hooks/10.ros.sh.em#L33
- https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/indigo-devel/core/roslib/env-hooks/10.ros.bat.em#L32

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-03-07**:
Okay, that's helpful, thanks. My specific interest is detecting hardware at setup time, for example to optionally launch drivers depending on paths present in /dev (or equivalent detecting schemes on other platforms).